# Finding the branch of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am having a really hard time understanding exactly how to determine the Riemann surface of a complex function f(z). I understand the concept: images of these complex functions are periodic, and so they map to the complex plane (not including the branch cut) infinitely many times. Each of these planes is a branch (sub-question here: does it not always map to the whole plane?), and drawing how the f(z) moves from one branch to another is how you show the Riemann surface for f(z).

So given any complex function, how exactly do I find the branch cuts? Is it by checking the zeros or the undefined values of the function? If there are two branch cuts, how do I know which points are part of which branch cuts? (phase factors play a part here, I believe).

Basically, if anyone can give a vague step-by-step of finding the branch points/cuts of an arbitrary function and explain it to a dummy, it would help a lot!

Comment: Im not fluent enough to answer, but I would guess adding how much you know about Riemann surfaces  / book(s) you or your lecturer(s) are following would help

Comment: I don't understand what you tried to say (periodic, branch, how $f$ moves..). Do you have a relevant example of $f$. For a function analytic at a point $a$ let $\{f_\gamma\}$ be the set of all its analytic continuations ($f_\gamma$ is a power series at some point $b$ obtained from analytic continuation of $f$ along a curve $\gamma : a \to b$), with the natural charts this is the Riemann surface of $f$.

Comment: My question is, how do you find the branch points of a function? For example, I know that the branch points of f(z) = $z^2$ are 0 and ∞. The Riemann surface of f(z) can be constructed by weaving together the different planes/branches at the branch cut created by 0 and ∞. This is my understanding so far, please let me know what is wrong.

Comment: You mean $f(z) = z^{1/2}$, because around some point there are only two versions of it, with only 3 branches we obtain all its analytic continuations so we can construct its Riemann surface from  only 3 charts. For $\log z$ there are infinitely many local versions of it and we need infinitely many charts.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand better... But how come f(z) = $z^{1/2}$ has 3 branches?

Comment: It has 2 local branches ($f$ and $-f$), infinitely many branches (infinitely many kind of simply connected open subsets $\subset \Bbb{C}^*$), and 3 are needed to cover its Riemann surface : to cover $(-\epsilon,4\pi+\epsilon)$ with intervals of the form $(a,b), b < a+2\pi$ we need 3 of them

Comment: @reuns is there a simpler expression for $\sum_{d \mid n} \frac{\mu(d)\log(d)}{d}$? I feel like I've seen it somewhere...